# STM32L4 USB Won't Trigger Disconnect Interrupt

Tags: usb, interrupt, stm32

I'm working on a project with a STM32L4 micro-controller configured for USB and cannot seem to get the USB interrupt to trigger on disconnect. I set everything up using the STM32Cube utility and have tested a similar implementation on a EVAL board I received with a chip from the same family and that one works fine but for some reason on my actual board I can't seem to replicate the expected behavior. I will trigger the interrupt when I first connect the device, and it has settings to handle when a device is disconnected but that portion never gets triggered.

Has anyone dealt with something similar and may be able to point me in the right direction of what to look into?

Comment: Just to certain, the code or similar code works fine on an EVAL board but not on your custom (designed by you perhaps?) board?

Comment: Correct. Does not work on a custom board with similar wiring to the same processor, am seeing vbus line go high and low on connect and disconnect though.

Comment: So 100 % verified that it is not a hardware issue?

Comment: Thought the interrupt was triggered based off that VBUS line and am 100% seeing that the line goes to zero when the USB cable is not connected, not sure if the other USB lines could be causing that interrupt not to trip for the USB disconnect.

Comment: Have you connected the Vbus sensing to the right pin and enabled it in STMCube? Is Vbus connected directly to the STM32?

Comment: VBUS is connected to the correct pin and is enabled in STMCube. VBUS is connected to the STM32 after going through a 5V to 3.3V gate simply to bring the voltage down.